# Windows Workflow foundatation scheduling

Tags: windows, workflow-foundation

If I have an ASP.NET app hosting a worflow where a trouble ticket passes through a fairly standard flow....at one point there needs to be an escalation occurring if a ticket has not been looked at or resolved in 6 months.  Now lets say the 6 months have passed, but the IIS machine has been rebooted last month and not used.  Will the workflow escalate the ticket?
When/how does the runtime check conditions on long running processes?  Does it scan through the 1000's of workflows looking...or have an events table it checks?  Does it even handle this kind of out-of-process workflow?

Seems like it would be a very common situation for a WF to handle but i can't seem to find any information.

Answer (score 0):

You're not finding any information on this because you don't need any. It works. This is how it's designed to work. If the workflow host is configured to use the persistence service, then the workflow will be persisted when it's idle too long, and when the delay is over, it will be restored from the persistence store and resumed.